# Programming the PS3 Controller for User Input

Tags: cell, playstation3

I need to begin programming the input for the PS3 controller. Right now I'm working on the cell simulator and have been debugging code on there for some time now. I'm ready to move on to the next step of development which would be to get input from the user, specifically from the ps3 controller, but I have no idea how to start this or what libraries I need in order to do it.

If anyone could help me get started it would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

j00b, you can get input from gamepad using SDL joystick APIs. tried that myself with ps3 sixaxis controller, it works. i tried via usb only though, don't know if bluetooth gonna work.